# Impact and alternatives on requiring some of the same packages in every modules of my node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-modules

Let's say I have an application as following:

- `server.js` (main) is requiring different external node packages, like `underscore.js`.

  `var Underscore = require("underscore");`
- `server.js` is also requiring some modules defined in my application it-self; For example it could requires a Router module, to handle `Express` routes.

  `var Router = require("./sources/router.js");`
- I have then my `router.js` file as following :

  ```
  var Router;
  Router = (function() {
    function Router(app, oauth) {
      app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        // ...
      });
    }
    return Router;    
  })();
  module.exports = Router;
  ```

**Questions:**

- If I want to use `underscore` inside my `Router` module, should I re-require again ? Should I do that for every modules ? What is the impact? 
  I would end up with something like:

  ```
  var Router;
  Router = (function() {
    Router.prototype.underscore = require("underscore");
    function Router(app, oauth) {
      app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        // this.underscore. ...
        // using underscore ...
      });
    }
    return Router;    
  })();
  module.exports = Router;
  ```

  and

  ```
  var Underscore = require("underscore");
  var Router = require("./sources/router.js");
  router = new Router();
  ```
- I could obviously also inject as a parameter it when initializing `Router`, but this doesn't look to me like a viable option in an application where I may end up using dozens of packages, especially for very *general purpose* package like this one.

  ```
  var underscore = require("underscore");
  var Router = require("./sources/router.js");
  var router = new Router(underscore);
  ```
- Alternatively I could set the `underscore` var as a global one, but I don't really like this option.
- Is there any other options ?
- What is the impact of systematically importing packages in every modules - in term of execution time, memory ? 
  I would like to understand the behavior of the node engine in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should just `require` it again.  Node caches required modules, so the second time you `require` something it doesn't actually run that file; it just returns the cached object.  So the memory impact is basically 0 (an extra pointer to the same object, more or less) and the execution time is similarly negligible (the cost of a lookup in an object by the module name).

This means that the objects returned by the two `require`s aren't just identical; they're literally the same object.  Any change to one will affect the other.  Because of this, you can extend the module in one place and get those extensions everywhere.